# Always Show Images for Emails

Tags: 2.2-froyo, email, gmail, images

Is it possible to configure the built-in mail or Gmail clients to always display images?

Answer (score 2):

There is a modified version of Gmail app available [over on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9375517&postcount=30) if you feel like you really need to always show images and are willing to replace the "stock" gmail app.

It may require root, not sure.

**edit**
[here is another thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=932579) on a gmail that shows images all the time.